# Getting different UNIX time on server with PHP 5.2 vs another on PHP 5.5

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

Alright guys, this is driving me insane as it should be so f'ing simple. unix epoch, static point in time, should be universal assuming your configured to the same timezone (even then, they should be relatively the same), but instead I'm getting wildly different timestamps.

So here's what's going on. I have a PHP script on my local machine that is hitting an API on another box in the wild. I unfortunately have only limited access to the API endpoint as it's a wordpress server. Luckily I can at least modify the code to some degree.

#### Local machine: PHP 5.5.9

#### External machine: PHP 5.2.14

In both, I'm setting the same timezone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

When I make a request though the following timestamps (created by the `time()` function in PHP) are generated

#### Local machine: 1404500112 (Friday, July 04, 2014 07:55)

#### External machine: 1404485713 (Friday, July 04, 2014 11:55)

This, while also using unixtimestamp.com, which gave 1404500116

So, external machine is totally lame. But how is that so? Isn't the unix epoch static??

Any leads would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: yes, but what's the system clock on the "lame" server set to? PHP may have no knowledge that the underlying system clock is in some different timezone. e.g if the system clock is set for UTC-2, and PHP assumes it's set for UTC+0, then the UTC-6 of LA will work out to your 4 hour difference.

Comment: This has nothing to do with epoch so I edited your question. Epoch is for the 1970 start date.

Comment: Ah man, so if that's the case, time is actually revealing that the system clock for that box is off :\ gah, major pain in the rear. So I guess the only way to fix this would be either convince them to set a standard UTC+0 or compensate on the fly. Thanks for the help guys, cleared things up.

Comment: @Tronhammer It's not really the clock so much as the timezone - I notice the seconds are identical. I strongly suggest you do NOT compensate! You will make yourself crazy. Complain until they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The `time()` function always returns universal time, not local time, setting a timezone in PHP will make no difference.

I suspect the machine simply is installed incorrectly. The machine probably thinks it's in one time zone, then someone changed the clock to make it match his local time, but didn't change the timezone.

Try running the `date` command on the command line of the external machine. See what it says.

Also run `date -u` on both the local and external machine.